# Android m - set all permissions granted

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I upgrade my sdk to 23 (Marshmallow), And I used [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher),

And Everything are fine, But I need to grant all permissions in debug mode, to easily test.

I Searched about this question, but i didn't find any useful answer.

Comment: take the app from setting and gave permission

Comment: I need an approach to do it as part of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can grant the permissions via adb:

```
adb shell pm grant <PACKAGE_NAME> <PERMISSION>
```

> Grant a permission to an app. On devices running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher, may be any permission declared in the app manifest. On devices running Android 5.1 (API level 22) and lower, must be an optional permission defined by the app.

Source: [ADB Shell Commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html)

I would suggest to write a script to setup the test device. Or you create a gradle task which will be executed before any of your test cases will be executed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to do it except grant all permissions to app from settings